# download a file from database in php

Tags: php, json, ajax, datatable

I'm trying to download a file from database that has previously been uploaded.
The filenames are being displayed in the correct column but I want to create a download link for each file.
Using the following code to display data from my database into a datatable all information is being displayed correctly;

```
while ( $aRow = mysql_fetch_array( $rResult ) )
{        
    $row = array();
    for ( $i=0 ; $i<count($aColumns) ; $i++ )
    {
        if ( $aColumns[$i] == "version" )
        {
            /* Special output formatting for 'version' column */
            $row[] = ($aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ]=="0") ? '-' : $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];
        }
        else if ( $aColumns[$i] != ' ' )
        {
            /* General output */
            $row[] = $aRow[ $aColumns[$i] ];                
        }
    }

    $file == $row[7];

    if (file_exists($file)) {

        header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
        header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
        header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file).'"');
        header('Expires: 0');
        header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
        header('Pragma: public');
        header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file));
        readfile($file);
        exit;
    }   

    $output['aaData'][] = $row;
}

echo json_encode( $output );
```

I have tried following multiple articles/tutorials on both this site and others and have managed to wangle out the above code however, not working as I'd hoped.
Anyone able to see what I've done wrong and what I need to change to be able to make the filename within the column downloadable?

Comment: `filen` or `file` ?? And do you now that a `$_FILES` is only filled after a fileupload. And the part that show the code for the `download a file from database in php` part is missing. More usefull informations are needed.

Comment: This `$uplfile . basename($row['filen'])` makes no sense, because of the `$file = $_FILES['filen']['name'];$uplfile = "files/$file";`. And you have to write a script that is getting the file (for download) from the database and serve it to the client.

Comment: Finally if you mean with `download a file from database` and you are only meaning the filepath that comes from the database, the question is asked in a wrong way

Comment: @JustOnUnderMillions Yeah think I got wrong end of the stick with the article i followed. I've gone onto php site and added in code following their manual. Im not getting any errors now, however not sure now, how i would link the text within the table to the file stored? any help?

Comment: What about the id entry of the database, and create a url like `getFileById=$id`. And you should only query for the one entry that you want and use no loop for the part that is parsing the file.

Comment: I would recommend to use mysqli or even PDO for accessing the database because the mysql-libary is deprecated and remove since PHP 7.